# XSLT: How to delete line feed characters within elements

Tags: xml, xslt

i try to flat some XML-Code and therefore i want to delete line feed characters and multiple whitespace-nodes within special elements.

For example:

```
<root>
    <elment1>
        <element2>some text...
            <element3>some text...</element3>
            <element3>some text...</element3>
            <element3>some text...
                <element4>some text...</element4>
            </element3>
        </element2>
    </elment1>
    <elment1>
        <element2>some text...
            <element3>some text...</element3>
            <element3>some text...</element3>
            <element3>some text...
                <element4>some text...</element4>
            </element3>
        </element2>
    </elment1>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <elment1>
        <element2>some text... <element3>some text...</element3> <element3>some text...</element3> <element3>some text... <element4>some text...</element4></element3></element2>
    </elment1>
    <elment1>
        <element2>some text... <element3>some text...</element3> <element3>some text...</element3> <element3>some text... <element4>some text...</element4></element3></element2>
    </elment1>
</root>
```

Is there a way to produce this output with XSLT?

Thanks!

Edit:

I used following template for example:

```
<xsl:template match="element2//text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(&#10;|  +)">
        <xsl:matching-substring></xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

I used analyze-string, because normalize-space() deletes some necessary whitespace-characters. The question i have is, why isn't the template geting the "line-feed-nodes" within element2?

Edit 2:
I used `<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"></xsl:output>`. Without the output instruction it works.

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: In this case, because InDesign is not able to process nested XML-Code  respectively whitespace-nodes correctly. So i need some indented nodes in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template for those text nodes, perhaps using `normalize-space()` suffices:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element2//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

That way I get the output (http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LUL)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root>
    <elment1>
        <element2>some text...<element3>some text...</element3><element3>some text...</element3><element3>some text...<element4>some text...</element4></element3></element2>
    </elment1>
    <elment1>
        <element2>some text...<element3>some text...</element3><element3>some text...</element3><element3>some text...<element4>some text...</element4></element3></element2>
    </elment1>
</root>
```

Comment: i tried that before, but matching text-nodes within element2 doesn't effect line feeds. As a result the second and third element3 is still intended

Comment: See the result I get, I don't know why you say that matching the descendant text nodes of `element2` does not allow you to remove line feeds.

Comment: You are right. I used <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"></xsl:output>. With this setting it won't work. Thanks for the page by the way!